# how to read a text file inside html file and copy the contents into a variable using php

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm new to HTML and when I searched for various ways of reading a text file inside HTML file, I found this code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <title>Page Title</title>
    </head>
<body>
<?php
    $myfile = fopen("C:\Users\nuh\Documents\webdictionary.txt", "r") or die("Unable to open file!");
    echo fgets($myfile);
    fclose($myfile);
?>
</body>
</html>
```

The PHP code does not run inside HTML.

Using javascript, I could not find a code which reads each line into a variable.
Please suggest me another way to read the contents into a variable.

Comment: `\n` inside double quotes is treated as a newline.

Comment: When you say "the php code does not run" - what is the file extension that you are using? hopefully a php extension i.e. index.php. Do you have the web server running along with php language? Also, any files that you want to access should be placed into the web folder. Not all operating systems use drive letters, non-windows systems don't have a users folder and the backclashes maybe interpreted as escaped characters so the language will see you code a C:sersuhocumentsebdictionary.txt

Comment: The idea of the web is to provide the content from a server, not from the client's machine. What you want to do, is not possible on a web page using JS, you need at least a local server to read local files. Consider also [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) instead of a textfile.

Answer (score 0):

For security purpose, javascript and HTML can't access the user filesystem.

If the file you try to read is on the server you can simply use `readfile("C:\Users\nuh\Documents\webdictionary.txt");`

If the file is on the client side then there is no way you can access it from PHP directly. 
You have to use a form with file input and submit it to your PHP. This way the user will have to click and to choose the file and you will have to manage the content of the request.

I don't know about any 3rd party plugin to do it.